# Wifi Scanner Canon Pixma 3010 connection

Tags: wireless, scanner, canon

I have Canon Pixma 3010 Wifi printer/scanner. But the same is not getting detected by my Ubuntu 18 LTS. The printer is but the scanner is not getting detected by the same.

Comment: have you got solution. I have same problem. The printer connect with no problem through wifi router, but ubuntu just can't detect the scanner.

Comment: True the Scanor is not detectable. I complined to Canon they said that the drivers are not ready, hence no app for the same.